# NIGHTMARE (Night of the Living Dead - WAP conversion): Endless Loop of Reference/Reciprocal errors (Impossible Puzzle to Solve?)

Tags: asp.net

Please read this carefully in its entirety and think about it before replying.  It might be a simple fix but I highly doubt it.  You have to understand the scenario here and conflicts I'm explaining fully to be able to help me.

So I have copied over our web site code to a WAP project.  I got rid of any reference errors.  Believe me I've checked every single error.  Now here comes my problem and hypothesis (it can't be solved):

We have a master page which has a bunch of public properties in it.

Almost all our .aspx.cs code is referencing some sort of property from Master and using it.

However, on the flip side, our master page cannot recognize any of my user or custom control tags that I've registered in the Master page.  The register tags are fine.  These were all referencing just fine together in a Web Site Project (both the master page was referencing its references to some user and custom controls and any .aspx.cs was referencing any master page public properties jsut fine).

So, if you think about this, this could be an endless loop that can never get resolved in this WAP conversion.  Why?  Because the way I see it, if my Master page can't reference the few user controls or custom controls in it, my master page will not compile.  If the reason that my master page cannot compile and reference these user and custom controls is because there are "other errors" and those other errors being that .aspx.cs files error out because they get errors referncing the master page public properties then we have a real problem.  It's like both are erroring out because both relate to each other and have problems that cannot get resolve because they're related!  Do you catch my drift?

Let me give an example / analogy to put this into perspective.

**MyMasterPage.aspx**

(example code in it)

```
<%@ Register Src="~/WebControls/User/Navbar.ascx" TagName="Navbar" TagPrefix="ac" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="am" Namespace="[ourglobalnamespace].Controls.Custom" %>

<tr>
    <td valign=top runat="server" id="tdNavBar"><ac:Navbar runat="server" id="navbar"></ac:Navbar></td> (this references a user control and is blowing up)
</tr>

...

<tr>
        <td><am:NavigationPath runat="server" id="navPath" Seperator="&raquo;" /></td> (this references a custom control and is blowing up)
    </tr>
```

Right now I get errors saying it doesn't recognize either of the controls above for whatever reason I cannot understand

**MyMasterPage.aspx.cs**

```
   public BL.Store Store  
   {  
      get { return this.store; }  
   }  

   public BL.Product Product  
   {  
      get { return this.product; }  
   }
```

just showing some public properties we're exposing through the Master Page's code behind. These properties are referenced and used in .aspx.cs code behind classes throughout our code.

**Example .aspx .cs using the Master Page Properties:**

```
   protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)  
   {  
      int productID = Master.ProductID;  
      product = Master.Product;  

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            int productID = Master.ProductID;
            product = Master.Product;
         ...
```

**So imagine I now have 1500+ errors mainly due to 2 reasons and they are not becuase of reference errors (I fixed all that):**

**1)** Master Page cannot compile

**2)** Code-behind for .aspx pages blow up because Master page cannot compile therefore any references to Master Page properties cause the code behind to blow up

how the hell would I be able to resolve this if both errors practically rely on each other to be fixed?  It's impossible!

**3)** Designer files cannot be generated for those remaining files that have these problems.  So I am not able to right click the Master Page and those user controls in order to convert to web application so that it will successfully create the .designer.cs files for them

so we really have 3 problems (3rd being an after effect fo 1&2) that I have no idea how to resolve here all stemming from the Master page blowing up but could be blowing up because the code-behind pages are blowing up that reference the properties of the master page that is also blowing up!  Do you catch my drift?

I hope it's something stupid simple that I've overlooked but I've spent a couple days on this and I see nothing else that will allow me to resolve this mess.

Someone shoot me to get rid of this conversion pain.  If anyone can help me resolve this I swear I will send you a fing case of Beer!

Comment: "Right now I get errors saying it doesn't recognize either of the controls above for whatever reason I cannot understand". Honestly, I think your effort would be better put towards trying to understand this rather than dramatizing the situation.

Comment: dude, when I've spend 2 fing days on this and I see NO WAY TO FIGURE IT OUT I'm going to have some fun with it.  My God, I was just making the post somewhat fun.  Get a sense of reality man and losen up.

Comment: and womp, why don't you try helping instead of a passive aggressive lame comment.

Comment: I really hope it wasn't you that decided to deface my blog about 3 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider this to help troubleshoot.

- Create a new test project.
- Copy your Master page into that.
- Solve any reference problems there.
- Get a successful build with just the Master
- Add Existing Item for your webcontrols.
- Add Existing Item for one of your content pages.

Comment: Tried that and it did not make a difference.  I wonder though.  In a Web Application Project is it possible to have custom controls (I'm not talking about user controls, I'm talking classes .cs for custom controls) in a folder in  your WAP project or must they be moved out into their own assembly and referenced from your WAP project?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there's normally a "true" error buried somewhere within the pile. They cn be quite hard to find though!

If you really think you've got circular build problems, try excluding items from the project until you get something that will build, then slowly add them back in. You may have to comment out methods or method bodies if you've got a circular reference between some classes.

**Edit to add:**

Circular references aren't allowed between projects, but within a project you can have them (sounds like that's what you've got). They're fairly common, and the build process can normally cope.

You also claim to have 1500 errors - I thought that Visual Studio stops counting at about 200? Wherever the limit is, you've probably hit it. Perhaps your "true" error is not showing up in the Error List.

Comment: yea, that's going to take me about 2 weeks to do.  Our project is HUGE.

Comment: we don't have circular references per say.  It's just dependencies that I think are intertwined here.

Comment: (In my experience, there's normally a "true" error buried somewhere within the pile. They cn be quite hard to find though!) that's what I spent all day today looking for and after resolving the rest of the references I found, I found nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, most of the pain from converting a web site to a WAP is due to namespace mismatches. Check that your master page and pages that use it are in the same namespace. And verify that the ,aspx files reference the correct namespace for the code behind files in the Inherits attribute.

Comment: Well relatively speaking they have to be in the same namespace.  For instance some of my controls are in [globalnamespace].Controls.User and some of the code behind is just in [globalnamespace].  I mean realistically you wouldn't have every class in the same namespace meaning just [globalnamespace] alone.  So not sure what you mean.

Comment: (And verify that the ,aspx files reference the correct namespace for the code behind files in the Inherits attribute.)  Yep, they are indeed.  that's one of the things I made sure of on day 1